# Matrix generation in R without loop

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix of the following kind in R: the number of rows is equal to n (supplied); in row i, for all i=1:n, the elements at positions n(i-1)+1 through n(i-1)+n inclusive are `1`, all other elements are `0`.
For example, if n=3, the matrix looks like

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Or for n=4:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Is there any way of constructing this matrix in R, for general n, without using `for` loops (or any other kind of loop preferably)?

The simplest / most efficient method (in base R) would be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution 1: `diag` returns the diagonal of a matrix. Repeat `each` element 3 times and (re-)coerce it into a matrix:

```r
matrix(rep(diag(3), each=3), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
```

Solution 2: `table` interprets the two vectors as factors and counts the combinations of their levels. Since each combination only exists once, you get the same result:

```r
table(rep(1:3, each = 3), 1:9)
#>    
#>     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#>   1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>   2 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
#>   3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.